# How to call backend code from frontend script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox, call

This script reads QR code and stores the resulting string in `txtcodigo`.
Upon clicking the textbox (or pressing enter), `msgSalida` is called.
But this needs to be automatic - it should not require a label click, but instead invoke the server-side method immediately when the JavaScript function acquires the QR code.

I'm wondering if there's some way to send an event to programmatically press the label, or something. I hoped `onTextchanged` would work, but it doesn't.

**ASP Markup:**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCodigo" AutoPostBack="True" ReadOnly="false"     runat="server" Width="371px" OnTextChanged="msgSalida" ></asp:TextBox>
```

**Frontend JavaScript:**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#reader').html5_qrcode(function (data) {
            $('#<%=txtCodigo.ClientID%>').val(data);                
        },
  . 
  . 
  .
  </script>
```

---

**Backend code:**

```
protected void msgSalida(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    if (txtCodigo.Text!=null || txtCodigo.Text!="")
    {      
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: You're referencing msgSalida in the OnTextChanged event handler, is this the right function that needs to get called?

Comment: How is `msgentrada` called? It's backend code and above is frontend code. I guess it is via post to some url or api? That part is missing to be able to help you

Comment: @MirkoVukušić hi!, well yeah it's called when you cick on the textbox and press enter, just like a simple button on aspn with c#

Comment: Well you can call $('#<%=txtCodigo.ClientID%>').blur(); after your have set value in textbox in your javascript to  trigger server side action.

Comment: @Hakunamatata Hi!, would you mind to explain  me a little bit more how would that be implemented Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could put a LinkButton on the page without Text and add a `OnClick` event to it. Now you can fake the clicking of the LinkButton by calling it's `__doPostBack` event with JavaScript after your code has filled the TextBox with the QR code.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function dummyPostBack() {
        __doPostBack('<%= LinkButton1.UniqueID %>', '');
    }
</script>
```